# How to move memory that is already allocated to another struct

Tags: c, struct, strdup

I have the following struct:

```
typedef struct{
    char* name;
    int score;
}Student;

typedef struct{
    char* name;
    int score;
}TeachingAssistant;
```

I have already `strdup`'d a string into the `name` variable in the `Student` struct.

I wanted to know how can I move that `strdup`'d `name` pointer variable to the `TeachingAssistant` struct so that I don't have to `strdup` again.

Answer (score 1):

You probably still want to use `strdup` when populating `name` in a `TeachingAssistant` struct.  If you don't, and simply copy the pointer, then if you `free` the pointer in one struct the other one becomes invalid.  You'd have to implement schemes to keep track of pointer references otherwise.

Better to just `strdup` the string where you need it, and `free` it for each copy when you don't need it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct{
  Student *XYZ;
  //char* name;
  //int score;
}TeachingAssistant;
```

Instead of definition you have right now , you can declare a pointer to struct `Student` as a member of struct `TeachingAssistant` , so that you can access `name` using it and no need to create duplicate .